# genotyping or variant calling in R

Tags: r, sam, variant-calling, genotyping, variants

Are there any good options for calling variants or even just a pileup from R? R is not ideal for this, but I'd like to integrate with other functions.

I found [deepSNV::bam2R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deepSNV/versions/1.18.3/topics/bam2R) which roughly does what I am looking for. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can always call out to the shell from R. Do you need the solution to be pure R, or could it be a library hosted on CRAN, bioconductor, or even conda? How are you controlling your dependencies?

Comment: @winni2k I was just looking for an R package. I am assuming the package is taking care of any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Samtools/bcftools/tabix is available in R via [Rsamtools](https://kasperdanielhansen.github.io/genbioconductor/html/Rsamtools.html).

[SEQprocess](https://github.com/omicsCore/SEQprocess/blob/master/Reference_Manual.pdf) also provides wrappers for different tools such as GATK and bowtie.

More utility packages are noted [here](https://docs.rc.fas.harvard.edu/kb/ngs-analysis-with-r/).